# Holding instance of javascript object in html document

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

First of all: I am quite new to Javascript and HTML. I encountered a problem/question that falls to the category beginner for sure, but I don't know what to search for to get the answer. I want to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        this.map = new GoogleMap();
        this.map.initialize();
    });
    var addMarker = function(lat, lng, address) {
        this.map.addMarker(lat, lng, address);
    };
</script>
```

The function `addMarker` I want to call from razor:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Companies)
{
    <script>
        addMarker(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude, '@item.Address');
    </script>
}
```

The problem is that `map` is not declared in the scope of the method. What is the correct approach to make this woking?

Comment: this call map variable from document, but actually your var store in window object. i think

Comment: If you are a beginner in javascript, then I would recommend you go learn about the `this` keyword. It is kind of tricky in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `this.map` but just `map` which will give you access to the global `map` variable that you have declared into the `window` scope:

```
var addMarker = function(lat, lng, address) {
    map.addMarker(lat, lng, address);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the `map` variable you declare on line one not `this.map`.